# Weighted SUM with rank in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, rank, row-number

I've been trying to compute a sum for each user of a table when the sum is weighted by the rank of each row according to some order. It's in the context of a video game, where the top score is worth 100%, the second one is worth 95%, the third is worth (0.95 * 0.95) * 100% and so on.

The formula can be simply described as `SUM(score * POW(0.95, score's position))`, yet everything I tried seems to hit a MySQL limitation.

First this option doesn't work because it seems the `ORDER BY pls.Score DESC` is called after the SUM (SUM doesn't seem changed by changing the order).

```
SELECT p.PlayerId, p.Username, 
        (SELECT SUM(pls.Score * POW(0.95, @i := if(@c = p.PlayerId, @i + 1, if(@c := p.PlayerId, 0, 0))))
        FROM player_level_stats pls, (SELECT @i := -1, @c := '') params
        WHERE pls.PlayerId = p.PlayerId
        ORDER BY pls.Score DESC) * 10 AS Score
FROM player p
ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```

Also I have to use this variable mess because I cannot have `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` inside a `SUM()`.

Now OK, my next thing to try was to SUM in an outer query so I can sort before summing:

```
SELECT p.PlayerId, p.Username, 
        (SELECT SUM(t.Score)
        FROM (SELECT pls.Score * POW(0.95, @i := if(@c = p.PlayerId, @i + 1, if(@c := p.PlayerId, 0, 0)))
            FROM player_level_stats pls, (SELECT @i := -1, @c := '') params
            WHERE pls.PlayerId = p.PlayerId
            ORDER BY pls.Score DESC) AS t) * 10 AS Score
FROM player p
ORDER BY 3 DESC
LIMIT 50;
```

Sounds good in theory but in practice there's a MySQL limitation where you cannot pass a parameter to a nested subquery (answers about this basically tell you to try something else). As the nested subquery is in the `FROM`, it seems really difficult to pass something to the intermediate query.

Of course there will always be the slow `SUM(pls.Score * POW(0.95, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM player_level_stats ipls WHERE pls.Score > ipls.Score)))` but this is O(number of scores ^ 2) instead of O(number of scores * log(number of scores)) making the whole thing much slower.

Is there any way to do this in MySQL? Alternatively is there any way to do this with MariaDB?

EDIT:
Here's an even minimal version (that do not work either)

```
SELECT p.PlayerId, (SELECT SUM(pls.Score * (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY pls.Score DESC)))
        FROM player_level_stats pls
        WHERE pls.PlayerId = p.PlayerId
        ORDER BY pls.Score DESC) AS WeightedScore
FROM player p;
```

This simply multiplies the score of each player by the rank of that score (best score * 1 + second best score * 2 + ... n best score * n). This is essentially the same problem but simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood the problem correctly, what you can do is a subquery with the sums and then use `row_number() over(order by)` to get the rank. Something like this:

```
SELECT playerID, SUM(score * weighted) AS totalscore
FROM
(
 SELECT 
  playerID, score, POW(0.95,(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by playerID ORDER BY score desc)-1)) as weighted
  FROM player_level_stats
 ) AS totals
GROUP BY playerID
```

Comment: Hi, what you are doing is `SUM(score) * POW(0.95, rank over other players)` what I want is `SUM(score * POW(0.95, rank of score over other scores for that player))` The multiplication really is inside the SUM, you can't pull it out because it changes for each score. See my edit for a simpler case of the same problem.

Comment: Ok, i understand now, sorry, I think we need to include partion by player as well

Comment: @Winter I've updated the query to do the weighted coef first and then the sum of score * weighted